# Django Deploy From Github to Server Like Capistrano with Simple Fabric Recipe

Tags: django, deployment, capistrano, fabric

I wanted to use Capistrano to deploy on my django app on my webfaction server but due to my purist tendencies, I wanted to do it in Fabric, in a way that Capistrano does. The thing that I liked most about about Capistrano is that automatically retrieves a repo's content and pushes it to a server.

The fabric recipes I have seen so far required me to do things "the git way", manually entering git commands to work with the repo, etc.

Is there a way to deploy a Django app in Fabric (or any other python package) "the Capistrano" way?

Sie Note: In case I really have to work with Capistrano, is there a way to bypass the assets precompile task and the rake db:migrate task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ive successfully used the scripts from [here](https://github.com/ashwoods/webfaction-django-fabfile) to deploy to webfaction.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bypass the assets compilation, just don't write this line in your recipe :

```
load 'deploy/assets'
```

If you don't want to run migration, just never type the migration command

```
cap deploy:migrate
```

If you want to remove some other behaviors (symlink, restart, update code to server) write chosen parts from this :

```
 namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart do ; end
  task :update_code do ; end #override this task to prevent capistrano to upload on servers
  task :symlink do ; end #don't create the current symlink to the last release
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who stumbles across this, here is a capistrano recipe that is so basic :

http://ygamretuta.me/2012/07/18/deploy-django-1-4-webfaction-capistrano/